# PHP shell_exec permissions in nginx

Tags: php, nginx, permissions, shell-exec

```
echo shell_exec('ls');
```

works fine.

But trying to copy something:

```
 echo shell_exec('cp index.php temp/index.php');
```

It doesnt show any error, but it doesnt copy.
I am using nginx with phpcgi.

Comment: probably a permission issue

Comment: copying in php copy() function also works great.. so where I have to set the permission ? How can I give total permission to nginx/php ?

Comment: What OS are you running? If it's a Red Hat distro do you have SELinux enforcing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try these two commands.

```
chmod -R 777 /path/of/your/app
chown -R apache:apache path/of/your/app
```

Comment: The op is not using apache. You should also explain what your commands do and why they are necessary. Also I think for apache your solution is a bit extreme.

Comment: @d_inevitable, you are right. I am using my phone. Therefore; I did not extend my answer with the required information that you are mentioning. And yes it is extreme, this should never been like that in production. This is just to troubleshoot and making sure is this is a permission issue or not.

Comment: Well your answer has been automatically flagged as "low quality" by Stack Overflow. Which is why you are getting so much critique here. So you might want to improve on your answer when you get to a desktop...

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the perms of the temp folder. Example:

chmod 777 temp

OR

Check the user you are running shell_exec with and grant him perms to write to temp folder:

echo shell_exec('whoami');

Comment: no idea.. 777 to all the folders and it doesnt work... The user is "apache" Im using centos 7, how can I give full access to this user?

Comment: try force copy: cp -f index.php temp/index.php

Comment: same result.. Pretty strange.. I have totally no permission to cp or mv